# python, what is the reason that: a=r'\\' >>> repr(a) "'\\\\\\\\'"

Tags: python

I have some questions about understanding raw string and repr(). 
So I tried thisin shell:

```
a=r'\\'
>>> len(a)
2
>>> str(a)
'\\\\'
>>> repr(a)
"'\\\\\\\\'"
```

I understand with the r, backslashes are treated as literal. But what is the reason that repr(a) comes "'\\\\'" as a result?

Answer (score 2):

You're viewing the `repr` result in the interactive interpreter, which prints out the `repr` of the results. You are therefore seeing `repr(repr(a))`, which contains eight backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

`r'\\'` is a two-character string composed of `\` and `\`. `repr()` gets its representation as a Python string literal. As backslashes start escape sequences in string literals, they themselves need to be escaped to accurately reproduce the original string, so `repr()` returns `'\\\\'` – a string composed of six characters. Finally, when displaying this string, the Python interactive shell itself uses `repr()`, which selects double quotes to avoid having to escape the `'` in the string it’s trying to represent, and escapes each of the backslashes again, resulting in what you see.

- `r'\\'`: `\\`
- `repr(r'\\')`: `'\\\\'`
- `repr(repr(r'\\'))`: `"'\\\\\\\\'"`

Answer (score 0):

The `repr` of a string is the literal that it would take to reproduce the string exactly. Since `\` is an escape character in literals, you need to double it up to get a single character in the resulting string.

When you type an expression without using `print`, you get a `repr` automatically. Thus the `\` are doubled up twice, the `repr` of a `repr`.